# Definition of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram)

> a parallelogram is a simple (non-self-intersecting) quadrilateral with
> two pairs of parallel sides.

Wouldn't it be enough just to say "a parallelogram is a quadrilateral with two pairs of parallel sides", i.e. that this automatically implies that the quadrilateral is *simple* if it has two pairs of parallel sides.

You may suppose that we consider parallelograms in 3D space (simply vector geometry);

Other sources require that it is convex and lies in a plane (for example the German version of Wikipedia):

> Ein Parallelogramm [...] ist ein konvexes ebenes Viereck, bei dem
> gegenüberliegende Seiten parallel sind.

In English:

"A parallelogram is a convex plane quadrilateral, where two opposite sites are parallel"

Same question here: May we omit "convex" "plane" and "opposite" in the sense that it leads to the same type of object.

Comment: Adding simple also rules out the possibility of a degenerate polygon - you could consider a line segment as a parallelogram with two 'trivial' sides, for example. Moreover, if we worked in hyperbolic geometry $\mathbb H^2$ then there would be even more examples of non-simple polygons with two pairs of parallel sides.

Comment: @jpmacmanus: Is ruling out the degenerate case the only thing in 3D euclidean geometry?

Comment: Yes, it would be enough.